# Get the list of stored procedures in order in the execution of a query

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

How do I obtain the list of stored procedures in their order of execution when executing a query? For example:

```
EXEC "SP_1" "(parameters)
```

I know that `SP_1` in his script uses `SP_1_A` and `SP_1_B` and they are executed in order - first A then B.

What I would like to know is how to obtain that list in order, so that I get a list of the stored procedures that were executed in order (events). Get it unknowingly in any query or stored procedure

Comment: Please don't SHOUT at us; it is often see as quite rude.

Comment: I don't think you can, sql server has no list of such data. Why not open the procedure and see in what order the are called there ?

Comment: I can't fathom why you'd need such information, what is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: You can get the procedure references using `sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities()` but I don;t think the ordering is guaranteed

Comment: Another problem is that the order of calling can be changed by the logic within a given procedure. How do you plan to address that? If a child procedure is called multiple times in a loop (or heaven forbid - goto)?